# Any other ways to produce a read-only Oracle DB for reporting?

Tags: oracle, dataguard

Besides using "Active DataGuard", any other way to produce a read-only Oracle Db for reporting by copying data from production Oracle DB?

The read-only Oracle DB should be in separate server with production Oracle DB, to make sure the loading in read-only DB will not affect the production DB.

Thanks.

Comment: Another option is to use Oracle Streams to replicate the data from production to the reporting server - especially if you don't need all tables from production on the reporting server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal backup and restore (or `dump` and `load`) to transfer the tables.

Note that the dumping will always affect your production server (it will need some resources to dump the tables). I don't know how much, though.

A different solution is to put the production database on a cluster filesystem (ie. something which supports mirroring of the data).

When you want to make a copy for the reporting DB, split the mirror. The production database should continue to run on the active mirror. You can now try to mount the second half of the mirror which gives you a corrupt database. Recover it as you would if the server had suffered a sudden power loss (because that's basically what you did).

Afterwards, you have a perfect copy of the production database with a minimum interference.